# jQuery hide and show from do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following in a event:

```
function onclickEvent () {
     $.ajax({
       url: "somePage.html",
       beforeSend: function( xhr ) {   
            $('#Element1').hide("slow",function() {                                                                                                                              
                $('#Loading').show("slow");
            }); 

        }

     }).done(function( data ) {                   
          $('#Loading').hide("slow",function() {                                                                                                                    
             $('#Element1').show("slow");                                                     
          });                                                      
    });

}
```

First time works well but the second time (second click) in "Done" ajax the loading does not hide, always is visible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first time I call the function

Comment: Can you update your question to include a a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This will make it much easier to troubleshoot your issues.

Comment: I do not understand, I'm chasing the goal is to show a loading for a ajax

Comment: if you switch `.done` to `.always` does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hid Element1 first, so you need to show it first on success/done. `show()` paired with `hide()` and vice versa seem to base the toggling on precedence. It seems to be the behavior. You may want to further read the documentation of these functions.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function onclickEvent () {          
    $.ajax({
        url: "somePage.html",
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {   
                $('#Element1').hide("slow",function() {                                                                                                                              
                    $('#Loading').show("slow");
                }); 
        }
    }).done(function( data ) {                   
        $('#Element1').show("slow", function() {
            $('#Loading').hide("slow");
        });
    });
};
</script>
<div id="Element1" style="display:block;">
    Element 1
</div>
<div id="Loading" style="display:none;">
    Loading
</div>
<button onclick="onclickEvent();">Click Me</button>
```

Using success

```
function onclickEvent () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "somePage.html",
        beforeSend: function( xhr ) {   
            $('#Element1').hide("slow",function() {                                                                                                                              
                $('#Loading').show("slow");
            }); 
        },
        success: function( data ) {                   
            $('#Element1').show("slow", function() {
                $('#Loading').hide("slow");
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are couple of things that need to be modified to get this to work the way I *think* you want it to work.

1. The `beforeSend` setting in the `$.ajax()` function is intended to give you a place to modify the request before you send it. This probably isn't the best place to call the first animation functions.
2. The animation callbacks and ajax callbacks seem to be causing a race condition -- it looks like it's possible for the ajax request to return while the initial animations are still running, which means that the `#Loading` element is shown when it should be hidden.

This example assumes that the `#Loading` element should be hidden by default when the page loads and that the elements should revert to their initial state even when the ajax request fails (`always` instead of `done`).

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#Element1').hide('slow', function() {
      $('#Loading').show('slow', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'somePage.html'
          })
          .always(function(data) {
            $('#Loading').hide('slow', function() {
              $('#Element1').show('slow');
            });
          });
      });
    });
  })
})
```

```css
#Loading { 
  display: none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Element1">
  Element1
</div>

<div id="Loading">
  Loading
</div>

<button id="button">
  Button
</button>
```

What's happening here is that when the `button` is clicked, the toggling animations (`hide()` and `show()`) are run, *then* the ajax request is sent as a callback from the `show()` animation so that the request doesn't go out until the #`Loading` element is visible.

Comment: Do you really want to delay the AJAX request until the `Loading` is finished fading in? That seems like an unnecessary time waster.

Comment: @Barmar That seemed to be the desired behavior. If it isn't, there's no real reason to delay the request.